# Referencing a Cookie within a Header in JMeter

Tags: cookies, header, jmeter

Within JMeter, I am able to generate a cookie and it is called `COOKIE_TestApi`.  I can see the value assigned to this cookie in the Debug Sampler and wish to use it in a Header for some HTTP requests.  I have an HTTP Header Manager specified as follows: `Name: Authorization`, `Value: Blah ${COOKIE_TestApi}`.

But the value of the cookie is not showing up in the HTTP requests.  All I am getting is `Authorization: Blah ${COOKIE_TestApi}` and it is not referencing the value of this cookie.

Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Comment: You need to add a user-defined variable, if you haven't done so already

Comment: I tried adding a user-defined variable with value Blah ${COOKIE_TestApi} but get the same response...

Comment: I find it easier using the CSV Data Set config to reference values. Store the cookie's value into a text file/CSV value and you should be able to name the variable COOKIE_TestApi, that should allow you to reference it as ${COOKIE_TestApi} in HTTP requests.\

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a global HTTP Cookie Manager in your test plan and have CookieManager.save.cookies=true set in your properties file. This isn't by default.